# How to prevent cURL from connecting to localhost?

Tags: php, security, curl, localhost

I'm implementing a PHP service that allows a bookmarking app to fetch the page titles of URLs. The server will download the HTML and extract the page title, but this requires that the user provides the URL to fetch.

From a security standpoint, I'm thinking that the user could attack the localhost to see if there are any HTTP services that are not exposed externally.

I have tried to configure which network interface cURL should use, but this requires that the PHP be configured with which interface. That might be an issue when I run this service in a container like Docker which would make that more difficult.

Is there a configuration option for cURL that prevents connections to the localhost?

Or is there a way to tell cURL to only use the external network interface?

Comment: Couldn't you just ensure the URL provided by the user is 'external', i.e. starts with http(s)://www.

Comment: Create a function that merely do the cURL requests and do whatever URL filters you want to do inside it.

Comment: @jibsteroos yes, that's what I was going to do, but I was thinking if you could block cURL from localhost, then it's safer logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53974558/1067003), and this code in particular

```
$info=parse_url($url);
$host=strtolower($info["host"]);
if ($host === "localhost" || ((false !== filter_var ( $host, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP )) && (false === filter_var ( $host, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_NO_PRIV_RANGE | FILTER_FLAG_NO_RES_RANGE )))) {
    $errors [] = "localhost and LAN IP URLs are not allowed.";
}
```

(but as explained in the referenced answer, you should probably also watch out for non-http urls supplied by hackers, such as `file:///etc/passwd`, which would make curl return filesystem-local files..)

Comment: This isn't at all a secure protection. `http:///localhost/secret` breaks `parse_url`, and thus this check is easily bypassed.

Comment: @JammyDodger you certainly got a point there! php doesn't accept that url as a localhost url, this doesn't work, just generates an error: ```php -r 'var_dump(file_get_contents("http:///localhost/secret"));'``` - but curl (and libcurl) DOES accept it as a localhost url, this works: ```curl -v http:///localhost/secret```